# Laravel route with variable

Tags: laravel

I have controller with show function:

```
class CssController extends BaseController 
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $csstablepost = CssTable::findOrFail($id);
        return View::make('posts/csspost1', compact('csstablepost'));
    }
}
```

And my route:

```
Route::get('/css3/{id}', 'CssController@show' );
```

Everything is working fine and corect id is in route, but I want get $title in my route. I have title and id column in database. Why my route isn't working with title if i change all id to title, but works with id? Is there a way, to get my title in route name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are changing your query to `CssTable::findOrFail($title);` and `findOrFail()` looks for the PK on your table.  You'll want to change this too something like `CssTable::where('title', '=', $title)->firstOrFail();`.

**Full Example:**

```
class CssController extends BaseController 
{
    public function show($title)
    {
        $csstablepost = CssTable::where('title', '=', $title)->firstOrFail();
        return View::make('posts/csspost1', compact('csstablepost'));
    }
}

Route::get('/css3/{title}', 'CssController@show');
```

See more [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage).

Comment: Did you change `$id` to `$title` in `public function show() {}`?

Comment: I forgot it. But now i have this error - No query results for model [CssTable]. But i have title in my database like id. Why there is no result?

Comment: I don't use Laravel's Eloquent much, but it sounds like it is saying it can't find a row with the `$title` in the DB. Place `dd($title);` before your `CssTable::where()` function, this will output the `$title` and kill the script. Then can you try manually running the query `SELECT * FROM [insert_table_here] WHERE title="[insert_$title_here]";` and seeing if any results are returned?

Comment: dd($title); i get 1, and it is id of title

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstood your question. You'll need to go to `/css3/title-goes-here` not `/css3/1` for my solution to work. Did you want to do something different?

Comment: I have button, when i click it, then in webbrowser i want to see /css3/title-goes-here . Button works with id, so everything is correct in structure, but now i try to get title there.

Comment: My button action is {{{ action('CssController@show', array($item->getKey())) }}}"   Maybe there is problem, because getkey gets id because it is pk?

Comment: Yea, change `$item->getKey()` to `$item->title`?

Comment: Yup. Done it, but now i get css3/local%20hex and error No query results for model [CssTable].  First thing - how to get something else in %20 because title is local hex. Second - error. With id it get that what i want. Why now it isn't working, if it get the right title name?

Comment: Can you do another `dd($title)`?  The `%20` is how browsers automatically escape a space, so you should leave this as is and `$title` should equal `local hex`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code-

```
class CssController extends BaseController 
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $csstablepost = CssTable::where('id', '=', $id)->first();

        return View::make('posts/csspost1')->with('csstablepost', $csstablepost);
    }
}
```

Now go to route page-

```
Route::get('css3/{title}', 'CssController@show');
```

Hope, it will work.